# How to Fix 'The model backing the context has changed since the database was created.' in database first

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to connect entity to an existing database, but am having a hard time figuring out why I am getting the following error:

> The model backing the 'RPSContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

As I mentioned, I am connecting to an existing database. So I don't need entity to modify structure. I'd just like to be able to select/insert/update/etc.

### Design:

[image: DB Design]

### Model:

```
public class ProductAttributePriceAdjustment
{
        [Key]
        public int AdjustmentId { get; set; }
        public int StoreProductId { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductSizeId { get; set; }
        public decimal Adjustment { get; set; }
        public int PointsAdjustment { get; set; }
        public int ProductColorID { get; set; }
}
```

### Context

```
public class RPSContext : DbContext
{
        public RPSContext() : base("ApplicationConnection")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAttributePriceAdjustment>().ToTable("ProductAttributePriceAdjustment");
        }

        public DbSet<ProductAttributePriceAdjustment> PriceAdjustments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you _absolutly_ sure that the schema between the database and what the code expects is the same? Plus, I see some `int`s that are not `nullable`.

Comment: Like @gunr2171 said, your model doesn't match up to the database

Comment: @gunr2171 definitely not. How do I troubleshoot that? Or what should I try?

Comment: @Jonesy Can you show me what my model should look like?

Comment: Well if you are using database first, you can go to your edmx file, right click, then choose "Update from Database".

Comment: @gunr2171 Argh. I'm an idiot. Thank you. Can you post that as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every time I see this error it's because the database schema and the schema the code is expecting is not synced up. At some point the schema changed and you did not reflect your changes in code.

For example, you have a db column `Adjustment`, which is a money type **that allows null values**. However, in your c# class, it is of type `decimal`, which does not accept null values. There are also some other properties that are either not present, or the types don't match up.

Good news is that fixing it should be really easy if you are using database-first. It's as simple as going to your .edmx file, right-clicking an empty area, and choosing "Update Model from Database".

[image]

From there you can add, update, or delete items found in your database. Once you save the model file VS will recreate your model classes, and it should be synced up.

Just a note: if you rename a db column, VS will not delete the old column name from your model, and will throw errors until you delete the column from your code model manually.

Answer (score 1):

Go Package Manager Console
then go and check your migration history from migration folder and check for first time enable migration name

then

add-migration [FIRST TIME ENABLE MIGRATION NAME] -force

then update-migration

Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

In your dbcontext file ,
add :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MYDBCONTEXT>(null);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```